# Two blocks after each others Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two blocks inline:

```
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
```

I need to make them after each others as brick for mobile phones.

How to do that in Bootstrap?

Full code:

```
<div class="contacts col-md-12">
<div class="col-xs-6"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `col-xs-6` instead.

`sm` is for tablets and `md`/`lg` is for bigger screen sizes.

See:

[image]

Comment: I tried, it does not work, look code in question, please

Comment: Those should be inside a `<div class="row"></div>`

Comment: They're inside another col, with md even.

Comment: `<div class="contacts row">          
<div class="col-xs-6">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
</div>
</div>`

Comment: May be `col-xs-12 col-md-6`?

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap `md` means that the style will be applied to medium screen devices and above. In your case smartphones are small screen devices then you should use `sm` instead

```
<div class="col-sm-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6"></div>
```